# On integral domains over which special kind of modules are projective

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, modules, projective-modules, dedekind-domains

For an integral domain $R$ let $\mathrm{Frac}(R)$ denote its field of fractions. Then $R$ is embedded in $\mathrm{Frac}(R)$  and we can consider $\mathrm{Frac}(R)$ as an $R$-module.

Can we characterize all non-field  integral domains $R$ such that every proper non-zero submodule of the $R$-module $\mathrm{Frac}(R)$ is projective ?

If $R$ satisfies my condition, then since every $R$-submodule of $K$ is projective hence so are in particular the fractional ideals of $R$, and hence every non-zero fractional ideal of $R$ is invertible, thus $R$ is a Dedekind domain. But $R=\mathbb Z$ is a Dedekind domain which does not satisfy my condition . So  the family of  integral domains, that satisfies the condition I stated , should be Dedekind domain + something more ; I can't figure out what this something more should be .

Comment: Local pid's satisfy this property. It doesn't appear that semilocal ones (say with two maximal ideals) do, since if $x \in M_1 \setminus M_2$, then $R[x^{-1}]$ doesn't look like it is finitely generated as an $R$-module ...

Comment: @DavidHandelman :Yes , local PID's i.e. fields and DVR's do satisfy the property , but I don't know whether this is necessary or not. In fact if it could just be shown  that domains satisfying my condition are local then we would be done as local Dedekind domains are either fields or DVR https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_valuation_ring

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An integral domain $R$ such that every proper non-zero $R$-submodule of $\text{Frac}(R)$ is projective is a local principal ideal ring. (The converse is David Handelman's comment above).

Indeed, we have

> > **Claim.** Let $R$ be a [bounded factorization domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_domain), e.g., a Noetherian domain, with at least two maximal ideals. Then $\text{Frac}(R)$ contains a non-zero proper $R$-submodule which is not projective.
> >
> > *Proof.* Let $\mathfrak{p}$ and $\mathfrak{q}$ be to distinct maximal ideals of $R$. Let $p \in \mathfrak{p} \setminus \mathfrak{q}$ and let $q \in \mathfrak{q} \setminus \{ 0 \}$. Then $1/q \notin R[1/p]$, since otherwise we would get $p \in \mathfrak{q}$, a contradiction. Thus $R[1/p] \subsetneq \text{Frac}(R)$. But $R[1/p]$ is not projective over $R$ because it doesn't embed into a free $R$-module. Indeed, $1 \in R[1/p]$ is a non-zero element which is divisible by any power of $p$ and no such element exists  in a free $R$-module.

Comment: could you please elaborate on why $1/q \in R[1/p]$ would imply $\mathfrak{p} = \mathfrak{q}$ ?

Comment: And do you mean $\mathfrak{p}  ,  \mathfrak{q}$ are two distinct maximal ideals ? Otherwise you can't probably get an element from the relative complement of each , because it might happen that one of the prime ideals is just strictly contained in the other

Comment: May be we don't need $R$ to be a Dedekind domain for this claim ? If $1/q \in R[1/p]$ , then $rq=p^n$ for some $n \ge 1$ . Then $p^n=rq \in \mathfrak q$ , and since $\mathfrak q$ is prime ideal , so $p \in \mathfrak q$ , contradicting how we chose $p$

Comment: @users Agreed, I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Why a free $R$-module cannot have an element divisible by all powers of a prime ? If $R$ is a field then a free $R$-module can contain such element , but say I am assuming $R$ is not a field . Can you explain why a free $R$-module cannot have such an element ? I can conclude if $R$ is a UFD , but I am not assuming that ...

Comment: Actually , the situation seems even more difficult ... $p$ need not be a prime element , so basically you have to show that a free $R$-module ($R$ a non-field Dedekind domain ) cannot have an element divisible by all powers of a non-zero element of $R$ ....

Comment: @users The result is clear if $R$ is a Dedekind domain: the $\mathfrak{p}$-valuation of any non-zero element is finite. I fixed the newly changed hypothesis on $R$: being a bounded factorization domain is enough.

Comment: Any Dedekind domain is a bounded factorization domain ? Could you please provide a reference ? Thanks ...

Comment: ah I recall that Krull domains are bounded factorization domains and Dedekind domains are Krull domains

Comment: @users: This is more general: any Noetherian domain and any Krull domain is a bounded factorization domain, see Proposition 2.2. of "Factorization in integral domains" by D. D. Anderson, D. F. Anderson and M. Zafrullah, 1999 - free access http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002240499090074R